# SailsCasts User model validation

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am creating a sign up form by following the SailsCasts Youtube view by Ponzi Coder but I am having issues with the User model validation. If I take out the validation rules I am able to submit the form but I get the warnings below when I put the rules back in. Also, when I am able to submit it, only the ID and the CreatedAt are returned, nothing else:

```js
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "3 attributes are invalid",
  "model": "User",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "name": [
      {
        "rule": "string",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
      },
      {
        "rule": "required",
        "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
      }
    ],
    "email": [
      {
        "rule": "string",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
      },
      {
        "rule": "email",
        "message": "\"email\" validation rule failed for input: null"
      },
      {
        "rule": "required",
        "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
      }
    ],
    "password": [
      {
        "rule": "string",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
      },
      {
        "rule": "required",
        "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is my User model:

```html
module.exports = {
 
schema: true,
 
  attributes: {
  name: {
 type: 'string',
 required: true
   },
  
  email: {
   type: 'string',
   email: true,
   unique: true,
   required: true
  },
  password: {
   type: 'string',
   required: true
  },
  encryptedPassword:{
   type: 'string'
  },
 
}
};
```

And below is my UserController:

```html
module.exports = {
 // Gets the view: signup.ejs
 'signup': function(req, res){
  res.view();
 },
 
 //Creates a user with the info sent from the 
 //signup form in signup.ejs
 create: function(req, res, next){
 User.create (req.params.all(), function userCreated(err, user){
  //If there is an error
  if(err) return next(err);
  
  //After the user is successfully created
  //redirect user to the show action
  res.json(user);
 }); 
 }
};
```

Below is my signup form:

```html
<form action="/user/create" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputname">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputRetypePassword">Retype Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="RetypePassword" placeholder="Retype Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign up</button>
    
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I have been facing the same issue. I have tried using POSTMAN and with and without default BluePrints. I tried POSTMAN by sending the params as form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded or raw, along with Content-type header set to application/json. But nothing works. The only thing that works is if I give the params as query string parameters, which I don't plan to use for my POST requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put "name" attribut on your inputs :

```
<input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
```

become

```
<input type="text" id="Name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
```

Same for all your inputs. Don't forget to put "name" in lower case like your model.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around my issue. I had modified the middlewares in my http.js. in my case the bodyParser middleware was missing in the order. I might have done that when I integrated passport with sailsjs. Once I added back 'bodyParser', my post requests started getting the expected params.

Hope this helps someone.

```
in config/http.js

order: [
  'startRequestTimer',
  'cookieParser',
  'session',
  'bodyParser',
  'passportInit',
  'passportSession',
  '$custom',
  'router',
  'www',
  'favicon',
  '404',
  '500'
]
```