# Why is 'encryptedPassword' parameter being interpreted as undefined in sails.js project?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am working on a web app following irlnathan/ponzicoder's Sailscasts series as a guide. I have reached [Ep. 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaGpf7t5y0Q&list=PLf8i4fc0zJByWVBmMk8uJ0UEhTIGMnmPQ&index=5&t=5m13s) on creating entries for the 'User' model using a signup action. At this stage in the tutorial (precise time linked to), we see that the response page he receives is the JSON object of the User that was just created using the signup. I, however, get the following for my response page:

```
{
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "model": "User",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "encryptedPassword": [
      {
        "rule": "string",
        "message": "`undefined` should be a string (instead of \"null\", which is a object)"
      },
      {
        "rule": "required",
        "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This states that my 'encryptedPassword' parameter is somehow undefined by the time I am returning a response. However, when I log the json object I am returning to the response in my console, I get the following (which is what I expect to see instead of the E_VALIDATION response):

```
{ firstName: 'First',
  lastName: 'Last',
  email: 'email@domain.com',
  encryptedPassword: '$2a$10$q0TfKWnN47mucsZLybN8WeygPPMpYxp9VMGUgIjA./ipZBn.POuOG',
  lastLoggedIn: '2015-08-03T23:45:22.520Z',
  gravatarUrl: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7328fddefd53de471baeb6e2b764f78a?',
  createdAt: '2015-08-03T23:45:22.523Z',
  updatedAt: '2015-08-03T23:45:22.523Z',
  id: 39 }
```

So encryptedPassword is definitely being correctly created and defined.

This is a problem similar to the one faced by **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404485/sailscasts-user-model-validation)** user, except my problem does not lie in missing HTML name attributes. Stranger still, my problem specifically lies in the 'encryptedPassword' parameter and none of the others.

I must admit that since I am not using the exact same fields for my signup form as the tutorial, there may be some discrepancies which are causing the issue. However, I still haven't been able to figure it out after a few hours of debugging. Here's what I'm using

**Relevant code:**

*Signup action (UserController.js <-- following sails.js conventions)*

*And as a note for each of the console.log statements littered in the signup function, I get a non-null value for them all. I did this to verify that indeed encryptedPassword was not null/undefined*

```
/**
 * UserController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing Users
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {

    signup: function(req, res) {
        var Passwords = require('machinepack-passwords');

        // Encrypt a string using the BCrypt algorithm.
        Passwords.encryptPassword({
            password: req.param('password')
            // difficulty: 10,
        }).exec({
            // An unexpected error occurred.
            error: function (err){
                return res.negotiate(err);
            },
            // OK.
            success: function (encryptedPassword){
                console.log("1", encryptedPassword);

                require('machinepack-gravatar').getImageUrl({
                    emailAddress: req.param('email')
                }).exec({
                    error: function(err) {
                        return res.negotiate(err);
                    },
                    success: function(gravatarUrl) {
                        console.log("2", encryptedPassword);
                        console.log("2", gravatarUrl);

                        User.create({
                            firstName: req.param('firstName'),
                            lastName: req.param('lastName'),
                            email: req.param('email'),
                            encryptedPassword: encryptedPassword,
                            lastLoggedIn: new Date(),
                            gravatarUrl: gravatarUrl
                        }, function userCreated(err, newUser) {
                            console.log("NEWUSER", newUser);
                            console.log("3", encryptedPassword);
                            console.log("3", gravatarUrl);

                            if (err) {
                                console.log("err: ", err);
                                console.log("err.invalidAttributes: ", err.invalidAttributes)

                                // If this is a uniqueness error about the email attribute,
                                // send back an easily parseable status code.
                                if (err.invalidAttributes && err.invalidAttributes.email && err.invalidAttributes.email[0]
                                    && err.invalidAttributes.email[0].rule === 'unique') {
                                    return res.emailAddressInUse(); //some error that I have already defined somewhere else in my project
                                }

                                return res.negotiate(err);
                            }

                            return res.json({
                                id: newUser.id
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Attributes of the User model (User.js <-- following sails.js conventions)

```
/**
* User.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {

        //all the other attributes

        // The encrypted password for the user
        encryptedPassword: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }

        //more attributes

    }

};
```

*HTML of the signup form*

```
<form ng-submit="submitSignupForm()" id="sign-up-form" name="signup" class="form" role="form">

  <!-- irrelevant html -->

  <!-- P A S S W O R D -->
  <div class="control-group form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':signup.password.$invalid && signup.password.$dirty}">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="signupForm.password" id="password" required ng-minlength="12"/>
    <span class="help-block has-error" ng-if="signup.password.$dirty">
      <span ng-show="signup.password.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
      <span ng-show="signup.password.$error.minlength">Password must be at least 12 characters.</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <!-- more misc html -->

</form>
```

*And the signup controller*

```
angular.module('SignupModule').controller('SignupController', ['$scope', '$http', 'toastr', function($scope, $http, toastr) {

    $scope.signupForm = {
        loading: false
    }

    $scope.submitSignupForm = function() {
        $scope.signupForm.loading = true;

        console.log("clicked!");

        $http.post('/signup', {
            firstName: $scope.signupForm.firstName,
            lastName: $scope.signupForm.lastName,
            email: $scope.signupForm.email,
            password: $scope.signupForm.password
        })
        .then(function onSuccess() {
            window.location = '/user';
        })
        .catch(function onError(sailsResponse) {
            var emailAddressAlreadyInUse = (sailsResponse.status == 409);
            if (emailAddressAlreadyInUse) {
                toastr.error('That email address has already been taken, please try again.', 'Error');
                return;
            }
        })
        .finally(function eitherWay() {
            $scope.signupForm.loading = false;
        });
    }

}]);
```

So to reiterate, why on earth is encryptedPassword being interpreted as null?

Comment: OK so I just went home and decided to try debugging this thing with the built-in sails debugger and to my surprise it just ran cleanly and works as expected... I have not changed anything else so I have no idea what I did but I'm glad it works now.